# Is it possible/ how to put y labels on the margins of heatmap cell?

Tags: r, heatmap

I am creating a heatmap in R using function heatmap.2 with timeframe "0-3", "4-7"...as row names. It is a little hard to explain when describing the timeframe of it, as the timeframe actually should be 0:00-3:59, 4:00-7:59..

So is it possible to put "00:00", "04:00", "08:00".. as y-axis label between each row cells?

I looked through the help page of "heatmap.2", couldn't find the solution.

this is the plot I have
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9VbL.png)

Answer (score 0):

*"So is it possible to put "00:00", "04:00", "08:00".. as y-axis label between each row cells?"* No, I don't think this is possible; this also wouldn't really make sense, since a heatmap shows numerical data for different *categories* in a grid-like layout. The emphasis here in on *categories* (as in categorical data), so showing *numerical* values between row (or column) cells is not really meaningful.

That aside, you can easily re-label row (or column) labels with `labRow` (or `labCol`); since you don't provide sample data, here is reproducible example

```
# Generate sample data
set.seed(2018)
mat <- matrix(rnorm(7 * 6), nrow = 6, ncol = 7)
colnames(mat) <- c("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday")
rownames(mat) <- c("1-4", "5-8", "9-12", "13-16", "17-20", "21-24")
```

Show heatmap

```
library(gplots)
rowlabels <- c("0:00-3:59", "4:00-7:59", "8:00-11.59", "12:00-15.59", "16:00-19:59", "20:00-23:59")
heatmap.2(
    mat,
    Rowv = NULL, Colv = NULL,
    trace = "none", dendrogram = "none",
    labRow = rowlabels,
    margins = c(10, 10))
```

[image]